# update the string valued column that should be incremented by 1 in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my database, my column consists of 40 same records named `jee_phy_2` . I want to increment the number by 1 like `jee_phy_2` to `jee_phy_40`. Can anybody tell me

```
DECLARE @q_id  NVARCHAR(50),@txt bigint,@final nvarchar(50)
begin 

SET @q_id='JEE_PHY_1' 


UPDATE oems_question7 SET q_id=@q_id+1 WHERE id between 1 and 40

end
```

Comment: do you mean, you want to replace all `jee_phy_2` with `jee_phy_3` (increment 1 in all 40 records)?

Comment: yes it should be incremented by 1

Answer (score 1):

Is this what are you looking for ?

```
UPDATE x
SET x.q_id = 'jee_phy_' + cast(x.newNum as nvarchar(10))
FROM (
      SELECT q_id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [q_id]) AS newNum
      FROM oems_question7
      ) x
```

[fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3fb3e/2)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DECLARE @q_id  NVARCHAR(50)
begin 

SET @q_id='JEE_PHY_1' 

UPDATE oems_question7  SET q_id = SUBSTRING (@q_id ,0,CHARINDEX('_', @q_id,5) + 1 ) + ' ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR,CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING ( @q_id ,CHARINDEX('_', @q_id,5) + 1, LEN(@q_id) )) +1)
WHERE id between 1 and 40

end
```

Comment: the above shown code is not incrementing by 1, same string value is displaying for all records ...